# Alamofire multipart sending array of String

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipart

i want to sending multipart array of string.

ex)

```
let list = ["ffff","bbbb","cccc"] 
let params = [
    "a" : "a",
    "b" : "b",
    "list : list
]
```

a and b case

```
for (key, value) in params {
    multipartFormData.append( value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! , withName: key)    
}
```

but how to list send?

plz help me.

Comment: Hi, so which way in the answer did you choose to solve your issue. I have the same issue, but if we use the first way, I don't know which field should we put the json of all params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have two ways to do it:

**1:** Make whole params as a JSON

**2:** Make only the array as an encoded JSON string.

In your case you can use **1:**

```
let list = ["ffff","bbbb","cccc"] 

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: list, options: .prettyPrinted)

let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

let params = [
    "a" : "a",
    "b" : "b",
    "list : jsonString
]
```

Comment: thank you for help me! : ) but
If I send ["aaa", "BBB"], the server will send '[\ n "aaa", \ n "BBB" \ n]'
I get the value this way. Why?

Comment: So basically server need to handle it by the stripes method in laravel php.

Comment: umm... is it impossible then to send ["aaa", "BBB"]?

Comment: You can't pass array directly.

Comment: OK Thank you so much!